# Isolated Storage to Local App Data

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm currently updating/upgrading my Silverlight project to the new runtime/universal apps.

Can someone please help me with isolated storage to local app data?
I've had a look at msdn and other resources but I haven't been able to find a clear enough answer.

How can I save the text/data from a textbox in to the local app data?
Here is parts of the Isolated Storage code :

```
Imports System.IO.IsolatedStorage

Dim highscoreISO As IsolatedStorageSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings

highscoreISO.Add("Highscore", ScoreLabel.Text)

Private Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    If highscoreISO.Contains("Highscore") Then
        HighScoreLabel.Text = "Highest Score: " & highscoreISO("Highscore").ToString
        ScoreLabel.Text = highscoreISO("Highscore").ToString
    Else
        HighScoreLabel.Text = "Highest Score: 0"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Quickstart: Local app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx) It has code examples for both C# and VB.

If you want to continue working with files just get the StorageFolder object and then work with StorageFile objects. To get the app specific local folder do:

```
Dim localFolder As Windows.Storage.StorageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i had a look at that post a few times, however i couldnt find the part about saving data from a textbox to the local app data.

Could you possibly help me out please?

Comment: Take a look at the "Read data from a setting" part of the document. You just assign / read from localSettings.